# How can I use real values in range of case inside statement?

Tags: system-verilog

My intention is to use the SystemVerilog **case inside** statement **with real numbers** such as below.

I'm aware that **realtobits** could be a solution, but I wonder if it is tool-dependent whether I should use that or can this be used as well with some minor modification to it?

Right now it always ends up at the `default` message.

```
case (value_in) inside
  [-97:-20]:         return 4'hA;
  [-10.25:-1]:       return 4'hB;
  [13.78:12.25]:     return 4'h4;
  [29:13]:           return 4'h5;
  default: `info("no match");
endcase
```

---

SOLUTION: SWITCH THE VALUES STARTING WITH THE SMALLER ONE:
instead of [29:13] use [13:29] and so on.

Thanks to @toolic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case inside` works for me with real numbers on 2 simulators.

The problem with the code you showed is that some of your ranges are empty.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.13 *Set membership operator*:

> If the bound to the left of the colon is greater than the bound to the
> right, the range is empty and contains no values.

`[13.78:12.25]` and `[29:13]` are empty ranges.  You can swap the numbers; for example, `[13:29]` will include all values between 13 and 29.

Here is a runnable example which includes your code:

```
module tb;

function bit [3:0] foo (real value_in);
    foo = 0;
    case (value_in) inside
      [-97:-20]:         return 4'hA;
      [-10.25:-1]:       return 4'hB;
      [13.78:12.25]:     return 4'h4;
      [29:13]:           return 4'h5;
      default:           $display("no match");
    endcase
endfunction

initial begin
    $displayh(foo(-33.3));
    $displayh(foo(-5.5));
    $displayh(foo(13));
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
a
b
no match
0
```

Cadence's simulator produces warning messages like:

```
      [13.78:12.25]:     return 4'h4;
           |
xmelab: *W,CASEINV : Ignoring invalid range in case item.
```

> xmelab/CASEINV =  Range in VST_CASE_ITEM is not valid. It is either
> unknown or left range value is greater than right one

---

Also:

> The inside operator uses the equality ( == ) operator on **nonintegral**
> expressions to perform the comparison.

Keep in mind that the comparison is subject to the usual limitations of floating-point resolution.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to simply switch the values to have the smaller on the left side of the range ":" operator.

Here is how multiple range which are non contiguous in a single thread could be achieved:
https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/using-range-operator-case-statement..